# sqlalchemy column_property or similar for table object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm very new to FastAPI and SqlAlchemy.
I've a table like this

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String

Agents = sqlalchemy.Table(
'agents',
metadata,
sqlalchemy.Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
sqlalchemy.Column('name', String(500))
)
```

Now, when the values are saved into the `name` column, we save the encrypted version of the name using `Pgcrypto` module of `PostgreSQL`. If this was `sqlalchemy.orm` based table, then I could use `column_property` to encrypt and decrypt on the fly when saving and selecting. Is there anything similar for such table based object? Otherwise, for now, I've to manually decrypt value on each select like this

```
from sqlalchemy import select,func, LargeBinary,cast

select([Agents, func.pgp_sym_decrypt(cast(Agents.c.name, LargeBinary), '**SECRET_KEY**').label('name')])
```

You can see that I've to decrypt every time. Is there any way that I could just decrypt on the fly whenever I use that `Agents` table?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom type:

```
from sqlalchemy import String, func, type_coerce, TypeDecorator
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BYTEA


class PGPString(TypeDecorator):
    impl = BYTEA
    cache_ok = True

    def __init__(self, passphrase):
        super(PGPString, self).__init__()
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return func.pgp_sym_encrypt(
            type_coerce(bindvalue, String),
            self.passphrase
        )

    def column_expression(self, col):
        return func.pgp_sym_decrypt(col, self.passphrase)


Agents = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'agents',
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column('name', PGPString("**SECRET_KEY**"))
)
```

see more examples [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#applying-sql-level-bind-result-processing)

Comment: Hi, thank you. It did solve my problem. However, when I do a search on encrypted column field, it says that bytea and varchar can't be compared. I thought that in where statement it would automatically apply the column expression @R-M-N